# ASP.NET Core MVC controller not binding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, httprequest, fetch-api

Doing a request from the fetch api to the endpoint and the props do not bind.

The id and fileName are 0 and null respectively on the endpoint.

My fetch:

```
fetch(`https://localhost:44343/items/edit`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id:123,
                fileName:"asd"
            })
        })
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(error => console.error('Unable to update item.', error));
```

My endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromBody]int id, string fileName)
{
    return Ok(id);
}
```

The request payload shows that the values are being sent:

[image: network request]

I've tried using and not using the `[FromBody]` adding explicitly the route to the action, changing to PUT instead of POST (why the heck does the default for the update action is a POST??)

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class which will represent the json structure:

```cs
public class Request
{
   public int id {get; set;} 
   string fileName {get; set;} 
}
```

And accept it in the action:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Request r)
{
   // use r
}
```

[More on model binding in ASP.NET Core.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in previous comment, create an object model to represent the json

```
public class Request
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string FileName {get;set;}
}
```

At your controller action method

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("items/edit")]
   public IActionResult Edit([FromBody] Request req)
   {
     return Ok();
   }
```